# Is it possible to send the same domain to a different vhost on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, lamp

I need to send my local users on my LAN who visit mydomain.com to virtual host A. Then external visitors from the web who visit mydomain.com are redirected to virtual host B. The reason being; I would like to seamlessly log in my local users using something like kerberos and external visitors must login through a form. Is this possible. I am using Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment but I don't have the reputation.
This question was asked and answered here: [Apache virtual host based on *source* IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/296617/apache-virtual-host-based-on-source-ip)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Thanks for the answer! but it's recommended that you copy or describe the relevant parts of the procedure, since links to external resources can become obsolete.